RVM Ruby 3.1.4 fails to install on macOS Sonoma due to perl5.18
I'm trying to install Ruby 3.1.4 version on Sonoma 14.4 with rvm and got this error:
Error running '/Users/username/.rvm/src/ruby-3.1.4/autogen.sh', please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/1712225389_ruby-3.1.4/autogen.sh.log
There has been an error while running autogen.sh. Halting the installation.

This is error in autogen.sh.log file:
/Users/username/.rvm/src/ruby-3.1.4/autogen.sh:
/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin/autoreconf: /usr/bin/perl5.18: bad interpreter: No such file or directory /Users/username/.rvm/src/ruby-3.1.4/autogen.sh: line 17: /usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin/autoreconf: Undefined error: 0

My perl version perl -v
This is perl 5, version 38, subversion 2 (v5.38.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
In /usr/bin/ I have installed perl5.30 and perl5.34 versions.
Can't understand why is stuck on version 5.18? Could you please help.
Thank you.
I tried to run:
rvm install 3.1.4 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3) 
rvm install 3.1.4 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline) --with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml) --disable-dtrace --disable-docs

but still getting the same error.

My guess is that sonoma uses perl 5.30, whereas /usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin/autoreconf was installed for use with the older /usr/bin/perl5.18. Try to upgrade autoconf

For reference, line 17 in autogen.sh is: exec ${AUTORECONF:-autoreconf} ${symlink} "$@" ${srcdir:+"$srcdir"}

I had a similar problem with installing ruby 3.3.5 via rvm. Reinstalling autogen helped(in my case via brew reinstall autoconf)
